# multiple wars on a single tomcat server with different spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have two WAR files that i need to deploy on a server.
the catch is that i cant run another tomcat on that server.
deploying two WAR files is easy but, is it possible to run them both while one of them uses

> Spring 3.8

and the other one uses

> Spring 4.1.4

which is the latest version?

Will it conflict?
answers like "try it out" are acceptable :) but i need to know for sure so i wont have issues in the future.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following for an explanation of how Tomcat's classloading mechanism works:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

> WebappX — A class loader is created for each web application that is
>   deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and
>   resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory of your web application,
>   plus classes and resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib
>   directory of your web application, **are made visible to this web
>   application, but not to other ones**.

If, then, the Spring Jar files are bundled in WEB-INF/lib for each application then you will have no issues. An issue would only arise if they were in some shared location.

Answer (score 1):

two different application under tomcat has two diffferent classpath and classloader so they don't conflict

latest as of today is 4.2.0 (under dev), you can keep track at http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/